# fatal exception asyncTask #1 host may not be null

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

i'm try to get json file from mvc 4 application using `webapi` 
but i get an error in `asynctask` `doinbackground` method

```
java.lang.illegalargumentexception host may not be null
```

when i track my code i found that it crash on jsonparser in getjson from url at the last line of this code

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String Url) throws JSONException
    {

        try {
            Log.d("tony","6"+Url);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // to connect to http
            Log.d("tony","7"+Url);
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(Url);
            Log.d("tony","8"+httpGet.getMethod());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

and this is my do in background code

```
 public JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
  // get url pointing to entry point of API
  String address = urls[0].toString();
  if (method.equals(LOAD_REQUEST)) 
  {
    return getJSON(address);

  }
  else
   return makeHttpRequest(address, method, parameters);
 }
```

the get json method

```
public JSONObject getJSON(String url){
       JSONObject j = null;
    try {
         j=parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return j;
 }
```

Comment: u have added intermnet permission?

Comment: yes i added internet permission

Comment: localhost:2100/api/products

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 localhost:2100/api/products
```

to

```
http://localhost:2100/api/products
```

Answer (score 1):

first correction :

```
localhost:2100/api/products
```

to

```
http://localhost:2100/api/products
```

Second, change

```
http://localhost:2100/api/products
```

to

```
http://ipaddress:2100/api/products
```

Because if you are using "localhost" you are pointing to the device host, and you need point the server.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `http://` to the `url` like that:

`http://localhost:2100/api/products`

Comment: are you friend of Tony ?